# Karate API - How to use regex in proxy configuration

Tags: proxy, karate

I am unable to use regular expression while configuring non proxy hosts.  When I add full hostname then it works   . Not sure if this is supported

proxy:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    uri: 'http://my-proxy.com:3128',
    nonProxyHosts:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        '*.api2.com' ,'*.*'                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    ]                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Adding '*' with a domain name is not working

Comment: this may need some contribution to resolve, refer: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1851